# any same way in js as I have in css?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to find the same thing, but have not found it yet. ( Been searching for hours. )

I got a hovered tie that gets to a big square.
(See link to see what I ment: http://rdv-design.com/stageverslag2/home.html

Just the different what I want is that when I hover the tie and the square comes out, the square will not disappear when I put my mouse on a div that's ABOVE it.
But when put my mouse outside the box of the hovered tie (square), I want it to disappear.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Learn some jQuery, that helps.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried something before posting? Have you any relevant code you are having problems with?

Comment: You could add a class on mouseover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `showdiv.js`, you've got this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.vierkant').hover(
        function() { 
            $('#tekst').show(); 
        } else { 
            $('#tekst').hide(); 
        }
    );
});
```

This isn't valid, the `else` is not part of an `if`. I think what you want to do is:

```
$('.vierkant').hover(function() { $('#tekst').show(); },
                     function() { $('#tekst').hide(); });
```

This call to `.hover()` uses two functions, one for when the mouse enters (show) and one for when the mouse leaves (hide). Once this is done, the hover event will be handled accordingly.

See also: the jQuery API for [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

*edit*: there is also the `.childen()` jQuery selector which may help. Although I believe the hover function should also apply to children of `.vierkant`, you may also wish to do:

```
$('.vierkant').children().hover(function() { $('#tekst').show(); },
                                function() { $('#tekst').hide(); });
```

assuming that the content in your `#tekst` block is actually a child node.

Comment: to be honest, I have it differently...

$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".vierkant").hover( 
   function() { 
   $("#tekst").toggle(); } );
});

It was just a try, since I am kinda new to JS.
This works thought, but still when my mouse gets over the text, the resized image (tie to square), gets removed.

Comment: I re-formatted your `showdiv.js` to make the scopes more obvious.